# How can I remove the new download popup?

Tags: google-chrome, popups, google-chrome-canary

Since a recent Chrome Canary update, you lose focus after downloading a file, because a new download popup appears. How can I make block this popup from annoying me?

[image]

Comment: If you are using canary you should know that there could be certain issues, especially with new features. You could always file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, already did. However, my fear is that this will stay that way so I'm already looking for a workaround...

Comment: again: file a bugreport

Comment: this "feature" just became default for me, after restarting the browser. I'm not running anything special. The feature *still* steals focus. They didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

chrome://flags/

Set "Enable Download Bubble" to "Disabled"

Comment: This flag is no longer available in version 122.0.6261.128. The answer provided by @TheRemoteCoder helped me.

Answer (score -1):

In a newer Chrome version, there's a feature in the settings under "Downloads / "Show downloads when they're done".